# Not able to run selenium scripts even after successfully installing selenium package to pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting error when i try to run below lines of code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: chrome failed to start
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Comment: is this driver the most recent one? latest release says 2.38 but yours says 2.33. try that

Comment: maybe your chromedriver hasn't permissions to be used by other processes

Comment: i tried with verion 2.38 and getting the below error

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: chrome failed to start
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64).....Can you help?

Comment: @RiaRenold I think, you should: set execution permission of the current user and chromedriver.exe. In your path, I sow "C:\\Users\\Admin\\"

Comment: @RiaRenold Update the question with the binary versioning info

Comment: I used a different syntax for retrieving Chromedriver and it worked for me

Comment: Shown below:dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
chrome_driver_path = dir + "\chromedriver.exe"